# API documentation on Swagger-UI

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, feathersjs

I am trying to document only the POST method for one of my services. Issue is Feathers-Swagger keeps adding all the other methods even if I specify `create` only . Here is the code
`  // Swagger Docs
docs = {
description: '',

```
// Define security to use for all requests
security: [
  { BearerAuth: [] }
],

// Document only the create method
operations: {
  create: {
    description: '.',

    parameters: [
      {
        name: 'data',
        in: 'body',
        required: true,
        schema: {
          type: 'object',
          properties: {
            property: {
              type: 'string',
              description: '.'
            },
            property: {
              type: 'string',
              description: ''
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ],

    responses: {
      201: {
        description: ''
      },
      400: {
        description: 'Bad request. The required parameters were not provided or invalid.'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have tried several methods . One is using only `create` in operations and removing the `all`. I expect only `POST` to be documented but instead its documenting every other method